# Run setup only once before a test run for a parameterized test in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I want to use a fixture to setup resources for a test which should create resources just once before the test starts but the test is parameterized.If I am doing it the below mentioned way it is calling the fixture for every combination of xx and yy, can anyone help me with another way to achieve this?

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('create_files')
@pytest.mark.parametrize('xx', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('yy', ['1', '2', '3'])
def test_operaration(self):
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Also is there any way to pass the value of xx and yy to `create_files` fixture for each run
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this helped to solve my issue:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def create_files(request: FixtureRequest):
    xx = request.getfixturevalue('xx')
    yy = request.getfixturevalue('yy')
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the scope of the `create_files` fixture to `session`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def create_files():
    ...
```